# How to form the json using the gson library to having loop thorugh the objects, lists?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm new to Java, as my background is JavaScript.
The input is entered through jsp page and their values are fed to form the json request.
I have dto objects as shown below, using which I have to form json, using gson library in Java to send as a request to postman. 
Now I was able to form the request, but not exactly don't know, if there is a better way tan the code I shared below and want to know, how to loop `visibilityInfo` array with different `visibilityType`, as the json request will have array of them in the request.

Please see the below dto objects and the main class which has the code

***MainClass.java:***

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.xxx.nsp.constants.Values;
    import com.xxx.nsp.dto.Address;
    import com.xxx.nsp.dto.SendCVConfirmationNotification;
    import com.xxx.nsp.dto.VisibilityInfo;
    import com.xxx.nsp.dto.VisibilityType;
    import com.xxx.nsp.json.NSPNotificationRequest;
    public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {        
            NSPNotificationRequest nr = new NSPNotificationRequest();       
            SendCVConfirmationNotification scv = new SendCVConfirmationNotification();      
            Address addr = new Address();
            addr.setAddressType(Values.addressType);
            addr.setAddressLine1(Values.addressLine1);
            addr.setAddressLine2(Values.addressLine2);
            addr.setAddressLine3(Values.addressLine3);
            addr.setPoliticalDivision(Values.politicalDivision);
            addr.setCity(Values.city);
            addr.setState(Values.state);
            addr.setZipcode(Values.zipcode);
            addr.setCountry(Values.country);
            addr.setCountry(Values.country);
            addr.setPhoneNumber(Values.phoneNumber);        
            List<String> accountNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
            accountNumbers.add("1233");
    accountNumbers.add("2234");         
            VisibilityInfo vi = new VisibilityInfo();
            vi.setVisibilityType(VisibilityType.THIRD_PARTY);
            vi.setAccountNumbers(accountNumbers);
            vi.setReceivingAddress(addr);
            List<VisibilityInfo> visibilityInfo = new ArrayList<>();        
            visibilityInfo.add(vi); 
             scv.setEnroleeName(Values.enroleeName);
             scv.setVisibilityInfo(visibilityInfo);
             scv.setCompanyName(Values.companyName);
             scv.setNickName(Values.nickName);
             scv.setHasClaims(Values.hasClaims);
             scv.setHasReturns(Values.hasReturns);
             scv.setCvURL(Values.cvURL);         
            nr.setTransactionId(Values.transactionId);
            nr.setClientId(Values.clientId);
            nr.setDestinationAddress(Values.destinationAddress);
            nr.setSendCVConfirmationNotification(scv);
            nr.setLocale(Values.locale);
            nr.setMediaType(Values.mediaType);
            nr.setPageId(Values.pageId);        
            Gson gsonObj = new Gson();
            String jsonStr = gsonObj.toJson(nr);
            System.out.println(jsonStr);
        }
    }
```

***SendCVConfirmationNotification.java***

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
public class SendCVConfirmationNotification implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2387905244655074588L;
    private String enroleeName = null;
    private String companyName = null;
    private String nickName = null;
    private List<VisibilityInfo> visibilityInfo = null;
    private boolean hasClaims = false;
    private boolean hasReturns = false;
    private String cvURL = null;
    private String emailId = null;
}
```

***Visibility.java***

```
import java.util.List;
import com.xxx.nsp.dto.Address;
import com.xxx.nsp.dto.VisibilityType;
public class VisibilityInfo {
    private VisibilityType visibilityType = null;   
    private List<String> accountNumbers = null; 
    private Address receivingAddress = null;
}
```

***VisiblityType.java***

```
public enum VisibilityType {
    INBOUND,
    OUTBOUND,
    THIRD_PARTY;
}
```

***Address.java***

```
public class Address {  
    private AddressType addressType = null; 
    private String addressLine1 = null;
    private String addressLine2 = null;
    private String addressLine3 = null;
    private String politicalDivision = null;
    private String city = null;
    private String state = null;
    private String zipcode = null;
    private String country = null;
    private String phoneNumber = null;
}
```

***AddressType .java***

```
public enum AddressType
{
    Consignee,
    Shipper,
    Reroute_Address,
}
```

***Expected Result:*** Need to add code to loop the `VisibilityInfo`, based on `VisibilityType`, as shown in expected result

```
{ 
  "transactionId": "12334567", 
  "clientId": "PPP", 
  "destinationAddress": "xyz@ggg.com", 
  "sendConfirmationNotification": { 
    "enroleeName": "Dev User 992", 
    "visibilityInfo": [ 
      { 
        "visibilityType": "FOURTH_PARTY", 
        "accountNumbers": [ 
          "1233", 
          "6722" 
        ], 
        "receivingAddress": null 
      }, 
      { 
        "visibilityType": "OUTBOUND", 
        "accountNumbers": [ 
          "6152", 
          "1277" 
        ], 
        "receivingAddress": null 
      }, 
      { 
        "visibilityType": "INBOUND", 
        "accountNumbers": null, 
        "receivingAddress": { 
          "addressType": "PPP_Store", 
          "addressLine1": null, 
          "addressLine2": null, 
          "addressLine3": null, 
          "politicalDivision": null, 
          "city": "downtown test", 
          "state": "NY", 
          "zipcode": "7539", 
          "country": "US", 
          "phoneNumber": null 
        } 
      } 
    ], 
    "companyName": "Clent_companyName", 
    "nickName": "DXXX1", 
    "hasClaims": false, 
    "hasReturns": false, 
    "cvURL": "http://www.google.com/test/sampleURL" 
  }, 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "mediaType": "EMAIL", 
  "pageId": "enroll" 
}
```

***Actual Result Obtained:***

```
{
    "transactionId": "12334567",
    "clientId": "PPP",
    "mediaType": "EMAIL",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "pageId": "enroll",
    "destinationAddress": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "sendCVConfirmationNotification": {
        "enroleeName": "Dev User 992",
        "companyName": "PPP_Clent_companyName",
        "nickName": "DU991",
        "visibilityInfo": [
            {
        "visibilityType": "THIRD_PARTY",
        "accountNumbers": [
            "1233",
            "2234"
        ],
        "receivingAddress": {
            "addressType": "PPP_Store",
            "addressLine1": "addressLine1",
            "addressLine2": "addressLine2",
            "addressLine3": "addressLine3",
            "politicalDivision": "politicalDivision",
            "city": "city",
            "state": "state",
            "zipcode": "zipcode",
            "country": "country",
            "phoneNumber": "phoneNumber"
        }
    }
],
"hasClaims": false,
"hasReturns": false,
"cvURL": "http://www.PPP.com/test/sampleURL"
}    
}
```

Can you please help me to write an effective code and add the array of objects based on `VisibilityType` to `VisibilityInfo` into json object created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you create a constructor for each class that takes all the required values. That way you can create the objects with much less code.

**MainClass.java:**

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import com.google.gson.Gson;
  import com.xxx.nsp.constants.Values;
  import com.xxx.nsp.dto.Address;
  import com.xxx.nsp.dto.SendCVConfirmationNotification;
  import com.xxx.nsp.dto.VisibilityInfo;
  import com.xxx.nsp.dto.VisibilityType;
  import com.xxx.nsp.json.NSPNotificationRequest;
  public class MainClass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {  

          Address addr = new Address(Values.addressType, Values.addressLine1, 
            Values.addressLine2, Values.addressLine3, Values.politicalDivision,
            Values.city, Values.state, Values.zipcode, null, Values.phoneNumber);

          List<String> accountNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
          accountNumbers.add("1233");
          accountNumbers.add("2234");

          List<VisibilityInfo> visibilityInfo = new ArrayList<>();        
          visibilityInfo.add(new VisibilityInfo(VisibilityType.THIRD_PARTY,
            accountNumbers, addr));  

          SendCVConfirmationNotification scv = new SendCVConfirmationNotification(
            Values.enroleeName, Values.companyName, Values.nickName, visibilityInfo, 
            Values.hasClaims, Values.hasReturns, Values.cvURL, null); 

          NSPNotificationRequest nr = new NSPNotificationRequest(Values.transactionId,
            Values.clientId, Values.destinationAddress, scv, Values.locale,
            Values.mediaType, Values.pageId);

          Gson gsonObj = new Gson();
          String jsonStr = gsonObj.toJson(nr);
          System.out.println(jsonStr);
      }
  }
```

add this to SendCVConfirmationNotification.java:

```
public SendCVConfirmationNotification(String enroleeName, String companyName,
  String nickName, List<VisibilityInfo> visibilityInfo, boolean hasClaims,
  boolean hasReturns, String cvURL, String emailId){
    this.enroleeName = enroleeName;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.nickName = nickName;
    this.visibilityInfo = visibilityInfo;
    this.hasClaims = hasClaims;
    this.hasReturns = hasReturns;
    this.cvURL = cvURL;
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
```

add this to VisibilityInfo.java:

```
public VisibilityInfo(VisibilityType visibilityType, List<String> accountNumbers,
  Address receivingAddress){
    this.visibilityType = visibilityType;
    this.accountNumbers = accountNumbers;
    this.receivingAddress = receivingAddress;
}
```

add this to Address.java:

```
public Address(AddressType addressType, String addressLine1, String addressLine2,
  String addressLine3, String politicalDivision, String city, String state, String zipcode,
  String country, String phoneNumber){
    this.addressType = addressType;
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    this.addressLine3 = addressLine3;
    this.politicalDivision = politicalDivision;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
    this.country = country;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

add this to NSPNotificationRequest:

```
public NSPNotificationRequest(String transactionId, String clientId,
  String destinationAddress, SendCVConfirmationNotification sendCVConfirmationNotification,
  String locale, String mediaType, String pageId){
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.destinationAddress = destinationAddress;
    this.sendCVConfirmationNotification = sendCVConfirmationNotification;
    this.locale = locale;
    this.mediaType = mediaType;
    this.pageId = pageId;
    //if this class includes any other properties, include them accordingly
}
```

Edit:

To get the expected result you specifies, you will have to edit VisibilityType and your main method:

**VisibilityType.java:**

```
public enum VisibilityType {
    INBOUND,
    OUTBOUND,
    FOURTH_PARTY,
    THIRD_PARTY;
}
```

**Main:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {  

      List<VisibilityInfo> visibilityInfo = new ArrayList<>(); 

      List<String> accountNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
      accountNumbers.add("1233");
      accountNumbers.add("6722");       
      visibilityInfo.add(new VisibilityInfo(VisibilityType.FOURTH_PARTY,
        accountNumbers, null));

      List<String> accountNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
      accountNumbers.add("6152");
      accountNumbers.add("1277");       
      visibilityInfo.add(new VisibilityInfo(VisibilityType.OUTBOUND,
        accountNumbers, null));

      Address addr = new Address(Values.addressType, null, 
        null, null, null, "downtown test", "NY", "7539", "US", null);    
      visibilityInfo.add(new VisibilityInfo(VisibilityType.OUTBOUND,
        null, addr));

      SendCVConfirmationNotification scv = new SendCVConfirmationNotification(
        Values.enroleeName, Values.companyName, Values.nickName, visibilityInfo, 
        Values.hasClaims, Values.hasReturns, Values.cvURL, null); 

      NSPNotificationRequest nr = new NSPNotificationRequest(Values.transactionId,
        Values.clientId, Values.destinationAddress, scv, Values.locale,
        Values.mediaType, Values.pageId);

      Gson gsonObj = new Gson();
      String jsonStr = gsonObj.toJson(nr);
      System.out.println(jsonStr);
  }
```

If I made a mistake or misunderstood your problem, just tell me and Ill try to fix it.

A few tips:

- Try to post less general questions and more specific questions requiring less code
- Look into Java docs, constructors, data types, etc.
- Don't use that many enums. In some cases they make sense (VisibilityType) and in some they don't (Values).